# How is create-react-app's build script affected by adding a server directory?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

So I'm using create-react-app and needed to add an express backend. I'm unsure now how adding this server directory within my application will affect CRA's build script -- for when I deploy my app. Will it be included in the outputted build folder? If so, is this fine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app` will ignore it. You would have to add your own custom scripts for deploying the express backed. It might be a good practice to separate them into two repositories.